# How to add LinearLayouts to a Parent View in a custom AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

So far I have been able to add a few LinearLayouts to another LinearLayout using this bit of code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.view_editscore);
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container1);

    for (String s : PlayersActivity.playersList) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_duplicate, null);

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        tv.setText(s);

        container.addView(view);
    }
```

And then I am also able to fill a custom AlertDialog with the `R.layout.view_editscore` View using this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.editScore);

    LayoutInflater in = getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(in.inflate(R.layout.view_editscore, null));
```

But for some reason, when I use the `setView()` to put the `R.layout.view_editscore` in the AlertDialog it only adds the version that was the "outer shell" before I added each of the LinearLayouts.

I have tried building the custom AlertDialog both before and after I fill the View with the other LinearLayouts but both ways are still yielding the same result.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Subsequently adding Views to an inflated layout does not alter the xml definition of that layout. Inflate the layout, add the Views to it, then set that layout object as the content View.

Comment: Okay, that works. Thanks for the help. I am still trying to grasp exactly what inflating is exactly.

Comment: If your code is as you show it in the second block of your post, that's not what you're doing. `in.inflate(R.layout.view_editscore, null)` is inflating a new instance of the layout, without any of the Views added. Take that out of the `setView()` method, assign it to a ViewGroup variable, add the Views to that ViewGroup, then use `setView()` with the ViewGroup.